# pyqt5: Can't run keyPressedEvent at GUI Window that made in QTdesigner

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, keypress

I made two ui with QT designer, and I called these ui with uic.loadUi().
I want to make a shortcut to exit code with keyPressEvent because all my GUI run as fullscreen. code will run in raspberry pi.
I found a code with keyPressEvent, but it works only on self.show() window. I don't use that window, but the event do not works on my ui window. How can I run     keyPressEvent in my ui window that made with QTdesigner?(self.ui and self.goodsUi)

```
class Form(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
```

I want to use this two windows

```
        self.ui = uic.loadUi("ui/a.ui")
        self.goodsUi = uic.loadUi("ui/goods.ui")

        self.ui.showFullScreen()
        self.goodsUi.showFullScreen()
```

I Want to remove this window/I don't use it

```
        self.showFullScreen()
        self.resize(10, 10)
```

this is keypressevent that works only in self.show()window

```
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_D:
            sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Form()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: or is there any other method to add a shortcut-like code for close all windows? please answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For a function to close all windows try this:

```
def keyPressEvent(self):
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    app.closeAllWindows()
```